# SQL Server join query optimization with group by

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Just for knowledge, I want to know that, can the below given query be achieve by any other feasible way like using group by.

```
        SELECT 
         GROUPMAS.GRPCODE, GROUPMAS.GRPNAME,
         GRPDTLS.ACCODE, GRPDTLS.ACNAME, GRPDTLS.DOA "ADMISSION DATE",
         LOANMAST.LOANCODE, LOANMAST.VCHDATE "LOAN SANCTION DATE", 
         LOANMAST.LANAMT,
         (SELECT SUM(RECPDTLS.INSTAMT) 
          FROM RECPDTLS 
          WHERE LOANCODE = LOANMAST.LOANCODE 
            AND RECPDTLS.VCHDATE <= '2009-03-31') AS REPAYMENT,
         (SELECT SUM(RECPDTLS.INTAMT) 
          FROM RECPDTLS 
          WHERE LOANCODE = LOANMAST.LOANCODE 
            AND RECPDTLS.VCHDATE <= '2009-03-31') AS INTREST,
         (SELECT MAX(RECPDTLS.VCHDATE) 
          FROM RECPDTLS 
          WHERE LOANCODE = LOANMAST.LOANCODE 
            AND RECPDTLS.VCHDATE <= '2009-03-31') AS "LAST PAYMENT ON"
     FROM 
         GROUPMAS
     JOIN 
         GRPDTLS ON (GROUPMAS.GRPCODE = GRPDTLS.GRPCODE AND GRPDTLS.DOA <= '2009-03-31')
     JOIN 
         LOANMAST ON (GRPDTLS.GRPCODE = LOANMAST.GRPCODE AND GRPDTLS.ACCODE = LOANMAST.ACCODE AND LOANMAST.VCHDATE <= '2009-03-31')
```

Table GROUPMAS structure

```
GRPCODE | GRPNAME
--------| -------
1       | A
2       | B
```

Table GRPDTLS structure

```
GRPCODE | ACCODE | ACNAME | DOA 
--------|--------|--------|-----
1       | 1      | name1A | 2007-07-05
1       | 2      | name2A | 2008-07-05
2       | 1      | name1B | 2007-07-06
2       | 2      | name2B | 2007-07-05
```

Table LOANMAST structure

```
LOANCODE | GRPCODE | ACCODE | VCHDATE  | LANAMT
---------|---------|--------|--------- |--------
1        | 1       | 2      |2009-01-06|2000
2        | 2       | 1      |2008-09-06|5000
```

Table RECPDTLS structure

```
TXNNO | LOANCODE | INSTAMT | INTAMT | VCHDATE
------|----------|---------|--------|---------
1     | 1        | 200     | 0      | 2009-02-06
2     | 1        | 200     | 10     | 2009-03-06
3     | 2        | 500     | 0      | 2008-10-06
4     | 2        | 1500    | 50     | 2009-03-28
5     | 2        | 500     | 0      | 2010-03-28
```

It will output something like this

```
GRPCODE | GRPNAME | ACCODE | ACNAME | ADMISSION DATE | LOANCODE | LOAN SANCTION DATE | LANAMT | REPAYMENT | INTREST | LAST PAYMENT ON
--------| --------| -------| ------ | ---------------| -------- | ------------------ | -------| ----------| ------- | --------------
1       | A       | 2      | name2A | 2008-07-05     | 1        |2009-01-06          | 2000   | 400       | 10      | 2009-03-06
2       | B       | 1      | name1B | 2007-07-06     | 2        |2008-09-06          | 5000   | 2000      | 50      | 2009-03-28
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you add the output of the current query?

Comment: One suggestion is you can put the three subqueries or "REPAYMENT", "INTEREST", "LAST PAYMENT ON" inside one query and do a JOIN (or a CROSS APPLY depending on the number of records you need).

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you have multiple subqueries all selecting from the same source, there's usually a way to merge them (as DVT mentions above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the sub queries in your select statement with `LEFT OUTER` OR `INNER JOIN` depending on requirements. If all LOANCODE records will have matching RECPDTLS records then use `INNER JOIN` else use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Keep your aggregate functions the same.

```
 ...
 Repayment=SUM(RECPDTLS.INSTAMT),
 Interest=SUM(RECPDTLS.INTAMT),
 LastPaymentOn=MAX(RECPDTLS.VCHDATE) 
 ...
LEFT OUTER/INNER JOIN RECPDTLS ON RECPDTLS.LOANCODE = LOANMAST.LOANCODE AND  Repayment.VCHDATE <= @HighDate
 ...
 GROUP BY
     GROUPMAS.GRPCODE, GROUPMAS.GRPNAME,
     GRPDTLS.ACCODE, GRPDTLS.ACNAME, GRPDTLS.DOA,
     LOANMAST.LOANCODE, LOANMAST.VCHDATE, 
     LOANMAST.LANAMT
```

You will need to run the query analyzer to see the efficiency gain between the old and the new queries.

**NOTE :** As I said above, be sure to  use LET OUTER JOIN if the LOANCODE is not required to have a RECPDTLS as an INNER JOIN will only return matches in both tables.

Comment: 2nd one is working well and fast as well, but first one is producing wrong result for column **REPAYMENT** and **INTEREST**, and it is taking 17 sec to execute and return 5414 rows, where all other queries are producing result in some milliseconds. Any way thanks @ross-bush

Comment: I removed the first one. It was joining the same table 3 times instead of once. I realized that after I saw that each aggregate had the same filter on the joined table, so you only needed one join.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts @ross-bush, but I think you should edit your answer again, as **GROUP BY** clause are also necessary to run this query.

Comment: But **LEFT OUTER JOIN** with **RECPDTLS** is not returning that **LOANCODE** of **LOANMAST** which does not have a matching **RECPDTLS** record. So what can be done for this??

Comment: Updated answer and added a note on left outer join usage. You can also continue to use a Left outer join, however, in your where clause add a WHERE NOT RECPDTLS.ID IS NULL, which ma or may not be necessary. If you only want matching records use and INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to simplify the request :

```
;WITH LOANMASTAGG AS 
(
    SELECT SUM(r.INSTAMT) REPAYMENT, SUM(r.INTAMT) INTREST, MAX(r.VCHDATE) [LAST PAYMENT ON], l.LOANCODE, l.VCHDATE, l.LANAMT, l.ACCODE, l.GRPCODE
    FROM @RECPDTLS r
        INNER JOIN @LOANMAST l ON r.LOANCODE = l.LOANCODE
    WHERE  l.VCHDATE <= '2009-03-31'
    GROUP BY l.LOANCODE, l.VCHDATE, l.LANAMT, l.ACCODE, l.GRPCODE
)
SELECT 
         g.GRPCODE, 
         g.GRPNAME,
         gl.ACCODE, 
         gl.ACNAME, 
         gl.DOA "ADMISSION DATE",
         la.LOANCODE, 
         la.VCHDATE "LOAN SANCTION DATE", 
         la.LANAMT,
         la.REPAYMENT AS REPAYMENT,
         la.INTREST AS INTREST,
         la.[LAST PAYMENT ON] "LAST PAYMENT ON"
FROM LOANMASTAGG la
        INNER JOIN @GRPDTLS gl ON gl.GRPCODE = la.GRPCODE AND gl.ACCODE = la.ACCODE
        INNER JOIN @GROUPMAS g ON (g.GRPCODE = gl.GRPCODE)
WHERE gl.DOA <= '2009-03-31'
```